# Problema al enviar formulario con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

estoy teniendo problemas al enviar formularios, no se cual es el problema, yo creo haber hecho todos los pasos para almenos mandar el formulario a phpmyadmin. comparto el codigo

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST["send"])){

    include ("../../connect.php");
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","phplogin");
    $nameC = ($_POST['nombreC']); //Se define la variable utilizando los name de los input
    $emailC = ($_POST['emailC']); 
    $comment = ($_POST['comment']);  

    $sql="INSERT INTO comments VALUES ('$nameC','$emailC','$comment')"; //Sentencia SQL

    $eject=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); //Se ejecuta la sentencia

    

    if(!$eject){ // Aviso de ejecucion
        echo"Fallo al enviar";
    }else{
        echo"Enviado con exito";

    }
}
    



?>
```

y aca les comparto el codigo del form, aunque todos los ID estan bien

```
<form action="comments.php" method="POST">
    <div class="BoxComments">  
            <input class="text" type="text" actionid="username"placeholder="Name" name="nombreC" autocomplete=false>
        <br>
        <br>
            <input class="text" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="emailC">
        <br>
        <br>
            <input  class="BoxComment" id="BoxComment2"type="form" placeholder="Comment" name="comment"></input>
        <br>
            <input  class ="ButtonComments" name="send" type="submit" value="Send"></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

Tabla SQL, la agrego porque el usuario BetoM me lo pidio.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments`(
    `iduser` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombreC` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `emailC` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
    `comment` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`iduser`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11;
```

Phpmyadmin:

[image: ifí]

Comment: que error te da? que valor tiene `$sql` cuando llega a `mysqli_query` ?

Comment: Como puedo ver eso @nax?

Comment: Así en tu código no veo ningún fallo. `$nameC = ($_POST['nombreC']);` esto debería quedar así sin `()` , es decir, `$nameC = $_POST['nombreC'];` al igual que el resto de variables obtenidos.  ¿Has comprobado que tu conexión funciona? Algo como `if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); exit(); }`. Prueba también en tu **phpMyAdmin** si funciona tu consulta `INSERT INTO comments VALUES ('Prueba','prueba@prueba.es','Soy una prueba');` y así compruebas que funciona o no.

Comment: Intenta escapando los datos: `$nameC = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nombreC']);` o, mejor aún, evita riesgos de inyección SQL cambiando a [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Podria ser la ruta del action dentro del form, no nos indicas como se llama el primer fichero en php.

Comment: Sería bueno también que revisaras los archivos log del servidor que utilices (apache, nginx...) Quizás haya más información que aclare lo que pasa

Comment: No me funciono ni pasar el inser into con valores predeterminados @D.Bulten. Como puedo solucionarlo? Por cierto, la conexion funciona de forma correcta

Comment: Podrías añadir en tu respuesta tu tabla `comments`, a ver si tienes algún fallo en él. ¿Has probado también en tu `phpMyAdmin` ejecutar tu consulta **insert**? Así en el código el único error que vi es que no estabas obtenido correctamente los valores por `$_POST`.

Comment: @D.Bulten Ahi actualizo el post con la tabla comments

Comment: Así a simple vista tampoco veo ningún error en tu tabla, solo usuaria UNSIGNED en iduser ya que es incrementada. Luego no entiendo porque haces un `include ("../../connect.php");` y luego parece que vuelves a crear tu conexión `$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","phplogin");` luego has probado tambien `INSERT INTO comments (userC,emailC,comment) VALUES ('$nameC','$emailC','$comment')` a ver si funciona especificando los campos.

Answer (score 2):

Estimado

El error se debe a que en el `Insert` no estas indicando cual es el orden de las columnas a insertar, así como esta *mysql* esta esperando a que insertes un numero en la posición donde debe ir `iduser` (En esa posición tu estas intentan poner `nombreC`).

El *query* debe tener este formato

```
INSERT INTO `comments`(`iduser`, `nombreC`, `emailC`, `comment`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4]);
```

Para el caso del *query* que esta en el script, dado que el `iduser` es autoincremental se asigna solo, por ende lo omitimos dentro del orden. Queda así:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `comments`(`nombreC`, `emailC`, `comment`) VALUES ('$nameC','$emailC','$comment')"; //Sentencia SQL
```

Si quieres ejecutar la consulta sin indicar el orden columnas a insertar, debes completar todos los campos según la estructura de tu tabla. Para el caso seria:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO comments VALUES (NULL, '$nameC','$emailC','$comment')";
```

En la ubicación de `iduser` se completa con `NULL`.

Puedes ver como funciona aca:
http://test.ingenierialabs.com/HatoriHanso/1/

Comment: No es un error no especificar los nombres de columnas en un `insert`, tambien es valido `INSERT INTO comments VALUES ('$nameC','$emailC','$comment')`, aunque personalmente me gusta especificar los nombres.

Comment: El problema de esa sentencia es que esta esperando en el primer valor indicado (`$nameC`) un valor numérico que es `iduser`. Cuando se ejecuta tu query con la estrcutura de tabla que presenta el OP, el error es el siguiente: `#1136 - El número de columnas no corresponde al número en la línea 1`

Comment: Creo que si `iduser` es un `autoincrement` no hace falta tampaco añadirlo, sera incrementado automaticamente. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187905(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN, simplemente se paso como NULL como has editado.

Comment: Si miras la documentación de mysql, ahi se indica que si no se especifican las columnas este hace un each de las columnas predeterminadas para setear los valores. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html. Por eso es importante respetar el orden de los valores a ingresar cuando no se indica orden de columnas en el query.

Comment: Tienes razon que se debe añadir NULL para que funcione, y alli estaba el error, y el orden es importante, pero no era tu primera respuesta. Mi +1

Comment: Entonces en la tabla deberia dejar 

`iduser` int(11) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

?

Comment: No, tu tabla esta bien, solo debes agregar un NULL en el query del insert o en su defecto indicar las columnas como sale en la respuesta.